# Intercept static method with aspectJ

Tags: java, spring, aspectj

I'm using Spring and trying to write my sample application with AspectJ. I need to learn how to intercept static method calls. In my example I'm trying to intercept the main method as follows:

Spring configuration file:

```
<aop:aspectj-autoproxy />

<!-- Aspect -->
<bean id="logAspect" class="com.package.Aspect" />
```

The main method:

```
public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        ApplicationContext appContext = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("Spring-Customer.xml");

        System.out.println("str");
    }
}
```

The asspect itself:

```
@Aspect
public class Aspect {
    @Around("execution(*App.main(..))")
    public void logAround(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {
        System.out.println("Intercepted!");
    }

}
```

But when I run the application, the only `str` string is being printed.

Answer (score 4):

You are using dynamic proxy approach where proxy object is created at runtime. This proxy object uses inheritance for proxying target methods. Since you can not inherit a static method, this approach wont work for static methods.

For creating proxy for `static` methods you need to use AspectJ's compile time weaving. You can refer [this](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-introduction-defn) link for more info. [This](http://henningpetersen.com/post/3/aop-and-compile-time-weaving-with-maven-eclipse-and-spring-2-5) might also help.

Comment: But is it possible to intercept non-static method in that way? I mean non static method of a non-spring bean?

Comment: No, it needs to be a spring bean.

Comment: Even if I use aspectJ integration?